# Can I text wrap a Java method name on multiple lines?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I know your first reaction will be "why on earth would you do this, your method names are clearly ridiculous" but it's because I'm using Spring Boot JPA where you can use the method name to construct the query for you by reflection (it's amazing). But when querying based on a few different columns and the entity variables have longish names the method name ends up being quite long and hard to read, so I was wondering if there is a way of splitting it across multiple lines?

At the moment I have something like (simplified for this question):

```
public List<Employee> findByFirstNameAndLastNameAndAgeBetweenAndBirthdayBefore(String firstName, String lastName, Integer minAge, Integer maxAge, Date maxBirthday);
```

And I would like it in my code to be more like:

```
    public List<Employee> findBy
                         FirstName
                         AndLastName
                         AndAgeBetween
                         AndBirthdayBefore
                         (String firstName, String lastName, Integer minAge, Integer maxAge, Date maxBirthday);
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Could you change the column names to have trailing underscores?  Would findByFirstName_AndLastName_AndAgeBetween_AndBirthdayBefore_ be easier to read?

Comment: @cup : For Spring Data JPA, underscores already have a special meaning in these method names. (e.g in a `PersonRepository`,  `findByAddress_ZipCode` would search for persons having an address with the given zipcode)

Comment: Shorten the name manually and have javadoc & autocompletion help picking the parameters in the right order. Do not use many variants of findBy. Consider that every call would be unreadeable heavy too. Elegant function names count too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is an invalid method declaration, Java doesn't allow you to extend method name to next line but even if it does it is still not a good practice.

I guess you trying to do this because of long method names, and even Spring Data JPA documentation suggests that if your method names are growing large you consider writing the query by using `@Query` annotation or use Query DSL.

Comment: Yeah I was considering shortening my method names and then using a nicely spaced out and formatted @Query annotation, I guess I was just being lazy and hoping someone else had a different way :)

Comment: lots of time by being lazy we find very efficient solutions

Answer (score 3):

A [method name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) is an [identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier), which is made up of [`IdentifierChars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-IdentifierChars).

`IdentifierChars` are defined as starting with a Java Letter, and thereafter may be a Java Letter or Digit. Those are described in the Javadoc of [`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-int-) (and `isJavaIdentifierStart`):

> A character may be part of a Java identifier if any of the following
>   are true:
>
> - it is a letter it is a currency symbol (such as '$') it is a
> - connecting punctuation character (such as '_')
> - it is a digit
> - it is a
>     numeric letter (such as a Roman numeral character)
> - it is a combining
>     mark
> - it is a non-spacing mark
> - `isIdentifierIgnorable(codePoint)` returns
>     true

And [`isIdentifierIgnorable(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable-int-) says (emphasis mine):

> The following Unicode characters are ignorable in a Java identifier or a Unicode identifier:
>
> - ISO control characters **that are not whitespace**
> - '\u0000' through '\u0008'
> - '\u000E' through '\u001B'
> - '\u007F' through '\u009F'
> - all characters that have the FORMAT general category value

So no, you can't have newlines in a method name.

Answer (score 1):

**No you can't include line breaks into you method name.**

Because a method name should be a valid "Java Identifier" ([see "Method Declarations" from Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4)) and a "Java Identifier" is made of Java letters or digits but no line breaks ([see "Identifiers" from Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8))

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.
>
> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).